# Jira automation validate members of team in if/then rule

Tags: automation, jira

Another help with automation in Jira.

I want to set an "IF/ ..." rule, to run only of the initiator is part of a Team.

If it is not possible to set that validation (being part of a team), at least how can i enter an array of user names or emails, and validate that the initiator is part of that list ?

Thaks in advance

Comment: The "initiator" is a custom field with type "User Picker"?

Comment: "initiator" is the smart-value to identify who is trgerring the automated action

Answer (score 0):

With automation, you can choose the condition "**User condition**" and set the configuration below:

**User**: set the option "**User who triggered the event**"

**Check to perform**: set the option "**is in group**"

**Criteria**: set **the name of the group** representing the team (or a **list of groups** representing the teams)

**NB**:

If you don't have a group(s) yet, you can create a group that contains the list of all the users (it will replace the array of "user names or emails").

Comment: Thanks.

Groups is not the same as teams.
I need to validate if user is member of a team, not a group

Comment: In automation condition "User condition", you can only check if a user is in a static list or is a part of a group(s) or has a role(s). You can't check directly if the user is a member of the team. So you can use an alternative either by using a static list of members (by setting the members directly in the condition) or by creating a new group and setting the members of the teams in this group. In that case, you can use the automation condition "User condition".